# Drupal Performace difference between cck field and text?

Tags: performance, drupal, drupal-6, cck

What do you think the performance difference would be?

20,000 nodes

Each node has a Link field. The number of values range from 50 to 200. The Links will have no title.

OR

20,000 nodes

Each node will have the links in the body field as straight text with filtered html. As so:

```
http://link1.com
http://link2.com
http://link3.com
http://link4.com
http://link5.com
http://link6.com
http://link7.com
http://link8.com
http://link9.com
http://link10.com
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends how/what you are going to use them. I doubt you are going to display 20.000 nodes at once. It's really hard to say much about performance, without a specific use case, and even then, you have to take caching and what not into consideration as well.

In any regard, CCK will probably always be a tiny bit slower, because you are extracting multiple values instead of a single value, which makes the query a tiny bit more complex. I doubt that you will be able to measure that on your drupal site though.

Another thing to keep in mind, is that using CCK fields will give you added flexibility, is it integrates well with views. So you can easily pull out the links and format them in different ways.

Comment: I guess my question was more on the database scaling side. I really should have compared the two in the database and then compared the query total of each before asking this question. You might not be displaying 20k nodes at once, but it might be in the 1-3k range times x number of queries...that could be quite a difference. Ill do the math then post the answer. Thanks for making me think about my question in a different way than I was originally thinking.

Comment: @picxelplay The question is not only database related, it's also very much dependent on how you display the node. If you do full node display, you will do a node_load. Doing this, CCK / body field wont matter, and if you display 1k, you get a very slow page. Full node displays are made for displaying a single piece of content no a list containing thousands of nodes. This is what I meant, by not being able to measure it on a drupal site, as the load difference is to tiny compared to what else is going on through the load and rendering of the node.

Comment: Also keep in mind how caching may alter / help this situation.  Drupal can cache pages depending on your settings.  You also have the option of caching things yourself in code a few ways, and your DB may have caching built in, too.

Comment: Are you talking about doing multiple (1k) node_loads at once? I meant if you had 1k users on viewing 1k nodes simultaneously. I don't think using a cck Link field would be feasible here. I was just doing some testing, and once you click "Add another Item" about 30 times, each time gets slower and slower. By putting the links into a single body/text area, they can still be utilized by views.  And also, you are saving yourself from having 2,000,000+ rows in that table for the cck link field.

Comment: @picxelplay, If you want to do 1k request per second, you don't want to use views or CCK. You would need to custom code a lot more. Generally I think you would get more performance ditching views than ditching CCK. But CCK isn't that useful with views. Another thing is that what's most important is your cache strategy.

Comment: Haha no no views will not be used whatsoever.  This wouldn't even require views in any way, shape or form. I just brought that up because you did before. We are totally on two different pages here.